# How can I fix this update Issue?

Tags: updates, update-manager

So far I have been told what the problem was but have been provided with no way of fixing it.

My computer is able to install updates, but when I hit check under the update menu it tells me to check my internet connection and gives me this error,

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anybody know a fix for this?

Is no one going to answer my comment down below?

Comment: Skateguy - to resolve this, please follow the instructions in the answer(s) shown in the linked question that is now in your question.  Thanks.

Comment: There is much more information on that page than I need and was hoping someone would clarify that information into an easy to understand response.

Comment: @Skateguy There is a scripted removal called `banish404` which you can try on that page (Ctrl+F then `banish404` to find it).

Comment: @Skateguy - follow the pictures in the first highest rated answer - just need to untick the PPA in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see that repository has no packages for precice:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubun-tor/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

You can safetly remove it.

Comment: Thank you for showing me that, How can I remove it?